# Mirror Drivers not working on Windows 7 64 bit computer

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, graphics-card, intel-graphics

I am having an issue getting any mirror driver to work properly on my computer. I always seem to get the same issue no matter which driver I user. I have tried the Mirror Driver in UltraVNC and Also the DemoForge Mirage Driver that is included in TightVNC.

These are the issues I seem to receive- this this the issue from DemoForge Mirage. The error from the other drivers are essentially the same just maybe worded slightly different:

```
Could not create device driver context!
Unable to map memory for mirror driver!
```

Considering this is happening with all mirror drivers I am thinking maybe it is an issue with my graphics card or Intel HD graphics.

My display adapters are:

```
Nvidia GeForce GT525M
Intel HD Graphics 3000
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem could be and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I hope that you are using a 64-bit signed version of the mirror driver,
otherwise there is no way that the driver can work on Windows 7 x64.
If the driver is 32-bit, you are lucky to even still be able to boot Windows.

In any case, here is a quote from [DemoForge Mirage Driver and TightVNC 2.0: How to use?](http://tightvnc.10971.n7.nabble.com/DemoForge-Mirage-Driver-and-TightVNC-2-0-How-to-use-td845.html)

> There are two major problems with DFMirage:
>
> 1. It's a third-party driver, we do not own its code, we do not
>       control its development and its license is not suitable for us.
>       It's just not quite compatible with development and business models
>       of our company.
> 2. Its future is indefinite. Windows Vista and Windows 7 seem to
>       migrate to new rendering architecture which is not compatible
>       with mirror drivers. It's not clear if it's worth to invest in a
>       technology that may become obsolete in next versions of Windows.
>
> I'd like to thank DFMirage developers, they've made a great work on
>   the driver and helped the TightVNC project a lot by providing DFMirage
>   to TightVNC users. However, we are not sure yet if it can be accepted
>   for TightVNC 2.0.
>
> I think we'll be able to make TightVNC version 2 very efficient even
>   without the driver. Note that TightVNC 2.0 easily shares an Aero
>   desktop which is absolutely impossible while using mirror drivers.
>
> Note that this issue is still under consideration, we have not made a
>   final decision yet.

This seems to say that there is a general problem with using mirror drivers
on later versions of Windows, so the problem may simply be that the DemoForge Mirage Driver is now incompatible with Windows.